# Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: pdb-files

I am using Visual Studio 2015.
When I run my program, it works perfectly but there are some outputs which show that there is some errors.

```
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Exper\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Lab3AssignmentOOP\Debug\Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-u..rsalcrt-apifwd-win7_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18878_none_4d8c75966cbcdb13\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-u..rsalcrt-apifwd-win7_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18878_none_4d8c75966cbcdb13\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-u..rsalcrt-apifwd-win7_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18878_none_4d8c75966cbcdb13\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-u..rsalcrt-apifwd-win7_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18878_none_4d8c75966cbcdb13\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-u..rsalcrt-apifwd-win7_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18878_none_4d8c75966cbcdb13\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-u..rsalcrt-apifwd-win7_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18878_none_4d8c75966cbcdb13\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lab3AssignmentOOP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

I checked the property of program
Linker > Debugging 
Generate Program Database File $(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb

I do not see any problem here, but why those errors are appearing when l run the program ? Are those important errors ?